# How can feature selection methods be evaluated?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, feature-extraction, feature-selection

**Hello,**

How can I choose the best fit feature selection method for a given dataset (textual data) ?

In Weka for example, there are several attribute selection methods (CfsSubsetEval, ChiSquaredAttributeEval, ... etc), and several search methods (bestfirst, greedy, ranker ... etc).

**My Question:** How can I know which attribute selection method and search method is best for a given dataset ?!

**My Guess:** Should I use cross validation to test the dataset after applying the feature selection filter ? so for example, that means if i have 10 attribute selection methods and 10 search methods, I will need to perform 100 cross validation test then pick the configuration with the highest accuracy !!!!!!! and I am assuming here that I am testing against one classifier only. So what if i have 2 classifiers (SMO and J48), will i need to perform 200 cross validation test ?!

Please correct me if I misunderstood something ...

Comment: You can use information gain to work out what are the most prominent features

Answer (score 4):

You can try information gain or principle component analysis to determine which features add the most to your classification(Information gain) or have the highest variance (PCA).

You can also use the techniques you mentioned. But whatever you do, you will have to evaluate it to see how effective it was, this could be quite a pain or a lot of fun depending on your outlook :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are different kinds of feature selection including filter and wrapper methods. Filter methods are classifier-independent techniques for selecting features based on distance, correlation or mutual information. I would advise that you check [FEAST](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~gbrown/fstoolbox/) tool and [mRMR](http://penglab.janelia.org/proj/mRMR/).

Regarding the wrapper models which are based on the performance of a particular classifier, you do not need to enumerate all the search methods you have. You fix one search method and apply the comparison proposed in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You should build a model on whole dataset, then perform feature selection (FS). If you have more than one model you can do scaling of feature importance by referring to RMSE or MSE. If you are familiar with R try searching "random forest AND feature selection" with google.